# How to show all records from MySQL table regardless of where statement

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
select * 
  from po_quotes left join po_quote_data on po_quote_data.quote_id = po_quotes.id 
  where supplier_id = 2 or supplier_id is null 
  group by po_quotes.id;
```

It shows: 
[image]

But I need to show one more record:
[image]

Main difference is `supplier_id` set to 1.

Is there a way to display missing record but null out values like in record 5?

Comment: Your query has a logical problem, because you are grouping/aggregating by the `po_quotes.id`, but you are trying to select all columns.  Please update your question with what you are trying to actually query here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not see all the records because of the `where`. So the solution is to get rid of it. Since you have a `left join`, the values where the joined `table` does not have a match will be nulled out.

```
select * 
from po_quotes 
left join po_quote_data 
on po_quote_data.quote_id = po_quotes.id 
group by po_quotes.id;
```

Also, `group by` is an aggregation, you will need to make sure you select the columns and averages you need instead of `*`.

Comment: but i need to select records only for selected supplier_id

Comment: You wanted to show the record having supplier_id of 2 as well along with records having supplier_id of 1 i your question. As a result I am puzzled